# code printing wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

Write a function first_last6(nums) that takes a list of ints nums and returns True if 6 appears as either the first or last element in the list. The list will be of length 1 or more.

My code:

```
def first_last6(nums):
    if nums[0] or nums[-1] == "6":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It is not returning the right answer for this test:

```
print(first_last6([3, 2, 1]))
```

its suppose to be `False`, while it prints `True`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0):

The original test checks if nums[0] is True or if nums[-1] is 6, to check if either is 6, should use:

if nums[0] == 6 or nums[-1] == 6:

Comment: Also make sure that it is 6 and not "6" like in NeilZ answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```py
def first_last6(nums):
    if (nums[0] == 6) or (nums[-1] == 6):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

In your original code, you check if the first element of the list evaluates to True (`bool(1)` is True in python). Instead, check if it is equal 6. And you check if the last element of the list is "6", instead of checking for 6.
A test in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> 6 == "6"
False
>>> 6 == 6
True
>>> bool(1)
True
```